How to connect 20 plus external hard drives to a computer?
Long story short is I am a photographer and over 20 years did it the wrong way. I have 20-25 external hard drives which include about 8 internal drives slotted into 4 docking stations. I have files on all of them but don't need them all all of the time but I want to determine what I have and maybe consolidate some of the older less than 2TB drives onto a newer drive. I'd love to get a NAS of sorts but don't know where to start being I would want a lot of what I have to be copied over.
This is my current computer a Lenovo Legion T5 26IAB7, 12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700 2.10 GHz with 64 GB RAM with Windows 11. When I connect a lot of the drives to 3 powered J5 7-port UBS hubs and connect those to 3 of 5 3.0 USB inputs I get blue screen of death and a restart is needed. When I just connect them when the computer is on, they are simply not recognized. I rescan disks in disk management but nothing works.
Could it be the power supply on the computer? Only about 5 of the drives are portable, the other are all plugged into electricity. My other problem, is all the drives and drive letters have been disjointed from my Lightroom catalog; any input on how to reconfigure that would be helpful as well.
I get all green checkmarks when I run my Lenovo system check and have the latest drivers. I have premium support with Lenovo but it's still hard to get them to makes sense of this.

I'm not a Windows expert, but I imagine its more likely a software driver issue or conceivably an issue with the USB hubs rather then a power issue (especially if its not bluescreening while making heavy use of your GPU)


1 for a clearly explained issue. You might add the total used space, too.


Most PCs should only expect to connect around 10 or so active USB devices at a time per "hub" (the front and back ports may be a single hub). Do the drives work okay with only one or two connected to each 7-port hub? To connect more drives at a time, you can look for PCI expansion cards that support more SATA or USB ports

Why can’t you just plug one in at a time and copy the files you need onto a new drive?

This issue came up in 1995 when I was doing Windows 95 support. There are only 26 letters in the alphabet, and since each drive has a drive letter, there are a maximum of 26 drives. The letters A and B are reserved for floppies. It's my understanding that Windows 11, part of the NT family of the Windows OS, still uses the same system. Whether you get the BSD or the drives do not function depends on the history of the use of the drives, as remembered  by the OS. Disclaimer: I haven't used Windows in years, and I can not call myself an expert.

@Wastrel Drive letters are still the default mount method, but NT-based Windows is perfectly happy to mount under any path. You could conceivably have a single C: root that then contains a \mnt\disk1 etc. much like *nix.

I'd suggest to rent some cloud storage as additional backup for the most precious files. 2 TB apparently cost around $10/month from the big three. That would put my mind at ease.

As you suggest, consolidating some of those drives onto larger drives should help, and it also leaves the originals as backup, should some issue occur. Overall, you do not seem to have prepared badly -- having 20 years of work on two sets of drives is a good idea; you might put the old backups in a fire safe and/or at another location.
If you don't need a NAS, then easiest might be external hard disk drives with their own "wall-wart" power supplies, avoiding a load on the USB ports and internal power supply. Eight TB drives from reputable sources such as Seagate and Western Digital, such as these at Amazon, are about US$150, 14 TB drives start at US$190, and so forth. Calculate the best combination for capacity, number of drives and price to meet your present needs, and perhaps for future use.
BTW, I simply unplug the USB cord on drives not in immediate use, reducing PC startup time, and protecting data. However, it's a good idea to access all every few months, to avoid parts getting stuck, and to check health.

This does not really answer the question though.

@davidgo, from OP: " I have files on all of them but don't need them all all of the time but I want to determine what I have and maybe consolidate some of the older less than 2TB drives onto a newer drive."

Yes but thats not a question.  The question is Could it be the power supply on the computer? and My other problem, is all the drives and drive letters have been disjointed from my Lightroom catalog; any input on how to reconfigure that would be helpful

Singular copies on one hard drive is not a backup, and should not be relied upon. There's an old systems administrator saying: "If it doesn't exist in at least 3 places, it doesn't exist at all". 3 Places might be a bit extreme here, but OP should at a minimum offload the data to a cloud storage service, in addition to their local copies. Hard drives fail, even SSD's... even if they just sit on a shelf or even if they're running 24/7. Don't rely on this system OP.

One caution about fire safes: Some of them are designed to protect paper — and if paper gets up to 250°F or even more, it's still fine. Hard disks, probably not. So you have to check if the rated protection is for documents or for computer media. If its for documents, computer media will be protected for a much shorter time.

There's 2 issues at hand here:
Number 1 is the fact that your computer bluescreens if you try plugging in too many drives. This may very well be your computer simply not coping with the power demands of many drives being put on all at once on the USB ports, which have not really been created for that purpose. This could come from a variety of problems, starting with the power supply, the motherboard VRMs or even the cases cables. I don't think it's very worth it for you to pursue fixing this, as it'll just be a money sink jsut to continue using a very flawed storage solution.
Number 2 is the very common practice of using non-backed up external drives as mass storage. We've all been here, and as you say, it's very much not in the "best practices" section of the book. It also happens that by fixing this issue, you also will be able to avoid triggering the first one, so I heavily recommend focusing on this first, and if your computer still bluscreens then you can focus on that (though I heavily doubt it will still be the case).
I work in IT for a field that has massive storage demands and appropriately massive storage infrastructure budget, so my apologies if the solutions I'm suggesting appear too expensive, but I'll try to suggest something that both fits your current and future needs, though keep in mind that the simpler the solution, the more money you'll have to spend eventually in order to upgrade when you run out of space.
At its core, this solution responds to your need: you need a centralized, redundant, mass storage device. I'm also going to assume a worst-case scenario that you have about 30 2Tb drives, as you don't mention your exact usage currently.
So you need about double your current usage (camera technology is only getting better and files larger), that means you need at least about 120Tb of usable storage to store all your current things and be set for a while. This is encroaching on rack-mount professional hardware territory, but it's still just in the reach of consumer-grade hardware, and given the costs and ease of use, this is probably about your best option.
That solution is a Synology NAS, more specifically the DS3622xs+ (about $2000), filled with 14Tb Toshiba MG07ACA14TE drives, one of the most affordable high-density drives on the market currently ($192 on amazon, $0.014/Gb), 12 of them. Synology is well-known as a begginer-friendly manufacturer who strives to make their products usable by anyone, while still providing competitive performance for the price. Their software has easy to use utilities for configuration of the storage-related tasks you need. The NAS is also capable of accepting a DX1222 expansion bay (about $1300, + cost of the drives), doubling your storage when you run out in a few years. This is about the most storage you can possibly get without venturing into the world of rack-mounted servers (which cost a lot more).
If you are math-inclined, you might have noticed that 14Tb*12 drives is a lot more than 120Tb. This is because all profesionnal-grade storage technology uses redundant storage, which sacrifices part of the total storage space in return for reliability, by duplicating your data that's one one drive across all other drives. If one drive fails, the data is still available and not lost, and when you replace it, it gets refilled with the reconstructed data. This is of course, all automated, and all you have to do is configure the server correctly when you first set it up (Synology's first-steps software should ask you the question clearly), and replace drives that have failed with new ones that have at least as much capacity (this gets easier with time, as capacity tends to increase). Synology's software can be configured to inform you by email that a drive has failed, or you can always look at the LEDs on each drive and identify failed ones by a red LED.
According to synology's own storage calculator, filling the NAS with 14 Tb drives and using the RAID6 configuration option, you should get just above 120Tb of truly usable space.
Once set up, the server will be available on your local network, and you will be able to offload your current hard drives on it, leaving them available to take on a shoot for storage in a pinch, though remember to always store your data on the NAS long-term.
Note that while the NAS itself provides instant redundancy against drive failures, it cannot possibly survive, say, a house fire. for this reason, I also recommend having backups of your data off-site, however given your current and future storage needs, I believe that's going to be prohibitively expensive.
One option is to buy 2 NASes and place the second one in another location (say, you keep the original in your studio if you have one, and place the second one at your home), and this is a common tactic that is supported by synology's backup utility. of course, the cost is then doubled, and you have to think about the 2 appliances as well as pay for their maintenance (eletricity, new drives).
Your second option is cloud backups. I believe currently Backblaze is the cheapest, but at an estimated $8k/year, that's not saying much. If you want the peace of mind that your data will be safe if the NAS burns, then this is effectively insurance that you can budget for, but I understand that it is very expensive.
Your last option is to accept that in the event of a freak accident, the data will be lost.
If you decide you want to buy a NAS, I suggest contacting a local IT b2b services company, they should accompany you through this and they generally have preferential prices with synology. I am also unfamiliar with tax law, but if this is for your business, you should be able to deduct at least part of the cost the NAS on your business' taxes. Talk with your accountant to be sure.

Great answer! Using backblaze may be overkill, though, since the OP needs that backup only for disaster recovery and not as an instant fail-over. For example, Amazon S3 storage in "Glacial Deep Archive" mode for 120TB would only cost about $1500 per year.

that is correct, however Glacier Deep Archive has prohibitive egress costs; you need to first put the data on a normal s3 bucket, then download it, both of which are very expensive. while ideally this never happens, it feels very bad to have to pay that much right after a life-changing disaster happens. Backblaze has very generous egress fees that allow you several full downloads before charging anything.

I notice the Synology storage calculator doesn't say how long it will take to initialize the array. ISTR something like 24 hours for four 4 GB drives, although that was on a lesser unit. Am I remembering correctly?

@AndrewMorton: in my experience, using good disks, we counted about 3 hours/Tb (i assume you meant 4 tb drives ^^). this is mostly a function of write speed, but also of processing power for the parity checks the processor has to do to initialize the drives. This will be true of any redundant storage solution however.

Lol, yes, 4 TB drives.

I see several comments agreeing with your answer (I add mine too), but it was sitting at "0" score? don't forget to upvote, everyone ^^

This reminds me of this Linus Tech Tips video on plugging in as many USB devices into a single computer, however you said you are using an externally-powered USB hub and not daisy-chaining them, so it should theoretically work.
You mentioned hard drives, note that hard drives have limited lifespan, and a dead hard drive can stop Windows from booting, so that might be the problem.
Hard drives can also deteriorate over time, but that wouldn't prevent booting, it'll show up as extremely slow or failure to read certain parts of the drive.
If the problem is solely not able to connect all of the hard drives at once, consider moving files into bigger drives so you need to connect less drives, or a NAS.
Personally I've built my own NAS by following the guides on the ServerBuilds.net forums, IIRC I used the NAS Killer 4.0 but there's a newer guide available, and also that I used TrueNAS instead of Unraid.
The other problem of drive letters being mismatched can be solved by re-assigning the drives' letter in Disk Management, right click a volume and select "Change Drive Letter and Paths..."
But if you have already moved files around to reorganize them, check Lightroom guides on how to relink files or something similar.


I have files on all of them but don't need them all all of the time but I want to determine what I have and maybe consolidate some of the older less than 2TB drives onto a newer drive.

You are having trouble plugging them all in at once, but you don't need to plug them all in at once to achieve your goal.
Plug in one large drive and one small drive. Move all the files from the small drive to the large drive (either directly, or via Lightroom). Unplug the small drive and plug in another small drive. Repeat, until all your files are on the large drive.
There's no need for all the drives to be plugged in at one time.
During COVID lockdowns, I went through about 18 old hard-drives before destroying them, making sure I wasn't about to lose anything I didn't have properly backed up. I never had more than about 4 drives plugged in at once.

Since you have a real tower PC you have the possibility to add PCI expansion cards that provide more USB ports, circumventing buggy mainboard ports. I have an ASUS B450 and apparently its USB ports suck: Sometimes devices would not properly connect, stall the entire computer until the connection ran into a timeout, that kind of problems. I got a PCI expansion card which usually works more reliably.
I did notice though that even with the card, I could run into a bluescreen when I used a mobile phone as a USB tether for mobile internet with a 3ft cable. With a shorter cable it works fine.
A simple google search shows that PCI expansion cards with multiple USB ports cost $30-$50, usually offering a mix of USB-A and USB-C ports.


Could it be the power supply on the computer?

Unlikely, because you're using powered hubs.
BSOD is a software issue. There is a driver that's misbehaving when you have that many drives attached. The solution for this part is not to attach that many drives. Attach one at a time until you get the BSOD, and then you know the limit. (Sorting out the software issue itself is another question and I don't think that's the road you want to go down with this question.)

How to connect 20 plus external hard drives to a computer?

What you're doing should work, in theory, but another approach you could try is to mount each drive to a separate folder, instead of a separate letter. You can do this by plugging in one drive at a time and then using the Disk Management tool to change the mounting options. If the BSOD is related to running out of drive letters, this might avoid it.
However, I suggest you reconsider your approach so that you don't ever need to answer this question. Instead, invest in a NAS, configure it with RAID if you can afford it, and then one drive at a time, copy your files to the NAS.
Due to the presumed importance of your files, you should consider a second, off-site backup. This could be as simple as taking all of those drives and leaving them at someone else's house, once you've copied them to the NAS.
